# Elasticsearch does not assign automatically shards of lost nodes

Tags: elasticsearch

I have three elasticsearch data nodes:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elastic_berries",
  "status" : "green",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 5,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 3,
  "active_primary_shards" : 50,
  "active_shards" : 100,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

When I remove the first node, I go into this state with some delayed_unassigned nodes which is normal:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elastic_berries",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 4,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 50,
  "active_shards" : 66,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 34,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 34,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

Then:

```
{
  "cluster_name" : "elastic_berries",
  "status" : "yellow",
  "timed_out" : false,
  "number_of_nodes" : 4,
  "number_of_data_nodes" : 2,
  "active_primary_shards" : 50,
  "active_shards" : 66,
  "relocating_shards" : 0,
  "initializing_shards" : 0,
  "unassigned_shards" : 34,
  "delayed_unassigned_shards" : 0,
  "number_of_pending_tasks" : 0,
  "number_of_in_flight_fetch" : 0
}
```

However, I am requesting only one replica, the cluster should automatically assigned unassigned shards and go back into green status. I have to run manually this command:

> curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings' -d '{
>       "transient" : {
>           "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "all"
>       } }'

To go back into green state. Is there a way to make this feature automatic?

Comment: Have you previously set `cluster.routing.allocation.enable` to `none`?

Comment: I have: -XGET 'localhost:9200/_cluster/settings'
{"persistent":{},"transient":{}}

Comment: I said **previously**, meaning before removing the node from cluster.

Comment: @AndreiStefan I did not touch cluster.routing.allocation.enable

Comment: How long did you wait before running that `"transient" : { "cluster.routing.allocation.enable" : "all"` command?

Comment: And `"unassigned_shards" : 34` stayed at the same `34` number, no progress?

Comment: Unfortunately no progress (the data is not very large).

Comment: Hm, let me find some time and test this.

Comment: I did another test on a fresh cluster and it is working fine :s

Comment: :-) I'm glad, but I'm still curious what went wrong the first time.